# Dynamic CSS Grid using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build a CSS grid based Vue component, something like this.

```
<Grid :cells="7" :columns="{xs: 2, sm: 3, md: 4, lg: 5}" />
```

The xs, sm, md and lg basically tell the component how many columns should be rendered based on some predefined breakpoints.

In the component's template itself, I am doing the following.

```
<div class="nugget-grid-item" v-for="cell of cells" :key="cell">
</div>
```

Now this generates my grid alright. However, I am not able to figure out a way to pass a different child to each of these cells created. Basically, each cell in the grid can have different content. How do I pass this content data from the Grid component? As children, slot, data prop or what else?

**Edit:** Most people are finding this confusing, so a little more details.

```
<div class="nugget-grid-item" v-for="cell of cells" :key="cell">
    {{cell}}
</div>
```

With this I will get a unique number in every cell of the CSS grid. I want this data to come from the user.

Something like,

```
<Grid>
    <div>content from here should go in Cell #1</div>
    <div>content from here should go in Cell #2</div>
    <div>content from here should go in Cell #3 and so on</div>
</Grid>
```

I have the entire component hosted here - https://github.com/Shreerang/Vue-Nuggets/blob/master/src/components/Grid/Grid.vue and the way to use it is in App.vue or above in this question.

Any help regarding this, is greatly appreciated! Looking forward to it!

Comment: What do you mean by `pass a different child to each of these cells`?

Comment: @tony19 basically, each cell in the grid can have different content. How do I pass this content data from the Grid component? As children, slot, data prop or what else?

Answer (score 0):

as @tony19 said... I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish... but maybe something like this could work for you....

```
<div class="nugget-grid-item" v-for="cell of cells" :key="cell">
 <div id="mychild1" v-if="cell === 'foo'></div>
 <div id="mychild2" v-else-if="cell === 'boo'></div>
 <div id="mychild3" v-else-if="cell === 'doo'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me try to be a little more clear @jremi.  
    <div class="nugget-grid-item" v-for="cell of cells" :key="cell"> . 
    {{cell}} . 
    </div> . 
With this I will get a unique number in every cell of the CSS grid. I want this data to come from the user.  
Something like,  
    <Grid> . 
        <div>content from here should go in Cell #1</div> . 
        <div>content from here should go in Cell #2</div> . 
        <div>content from here should go in Cell #3 and so on</div> . 
    </Grid>

Comment: Updated my question to better reflect what am looking for!

Comment: How does this get added to your template....     <div>content from here should go in Cell #1</div>

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to solve. How do I get <div>content from here should go in Cell #1</div> to show in my template?

Comment: What i mean... where does the content come from? How is it generated?

Comment: The user of the Grid component will provide it. Think of a product grid on a search/browse page example. The entire page is a grid, with a different product in each cell of the grid.

Comment: Can you provide example of what the {{cell}} data looks like?

Comment: that {{cell}} is basically the index. Take a look at https://ecommerce-vue-nuggets.herokuapp.com/ to see how it will appear.